# NSortDescriptor printing out and sorting incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

Ok I broke my problem into a simple more tangible problem to understand. So the code below has a sequence of numbers: 1,0,1,0 but when I go to print it out after it it sorted, it prints out: 0,0,0,0. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 SortedDetailFields * sorty = [[SortedDetailFields alloc]init];

NSMutableArray * fieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

BOOL fieldone, fieldtwo,fieldthree,fieldfour;

NSSortDescriptor *fff = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"numbersToSort"
                                                                    ascending:NO];
fieldone = true;

fieldtwo = false;

fieldthree = true;

fieldfour = false;



if (fieldone) {
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"1";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];

}else{
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"0";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}

if (fieldtwo) {
   sorty.numbersToSort = @"1";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}else{
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"0";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}
if (fieldthree) {
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"1";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}else{
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"0";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}
if (fieldfour) {
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"1";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}else{
    sorty.numbersToSort = @"0";
    [fieldArray addObject:sorty];
}




NSLog(@"By numbers : %@",[fieldArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[fff]]);

for (SortedDetailFields * detain in fieldArray) {
    NSLog(@"Number %@",detain.numbersToSort);
}
```

So my question is how would I sort and print the objects so they match a sequence 1,1,0,0? 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you are modifying the same object `sorty` and adding to the array, the last set value is zero as fieldFour is false. Try printing your array and you will have the same object added multiple times

Comment: There is a bit of a lesson here:  When you say that the data is being "sorted incorrectly" you completely miss the more likely case that the data is wrong to begin with.  When debugging, jumping to conclusions is not generally wise -- always verify each step of the process.

Comment: Hot licks I am all for improving the preciseness of my question, but I care more about learning from my mistakes.

Comment: My point is that you made a mistake in assuming that the symptom == the cause.  You need to learn from *that* mistake.,

Comment: I'm with you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comment of @Naveen Prasad R:

The simplest solution is to create NSDictionaries, a fresh one every time:

```
NSMutableArray* fieldArray = [NSMutableArray new];

[fieldArray addObject:@{@"field":@"fieldOne",@"value":"@(fieldone)}];
[fieldArray addObject:@{@"field":@"fieldTwo",@"value":"@(fieldtwo)}];
[fieldArray addObject:@{@"field":@"fieldThree",@"value":"@(fieldthree)}];
[fieldArray addObject:@{@"field":@"fieldFour",@"value":"@(fieldfour)}];

NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value"
                                                                    ascending:NO];

NSArray* sortedArray = [fieldArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
for (NSDictionary* dict in sortedArray) {
    NSLog(@"Number %@",dict[@"value"]);
}
```

This should work. Please also make sure that if you use '`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`', your original array wont change but a sorted version will be returned! (In my example '`sortedArray`')

Instead of the strings 'fieldOne', 'fieldTwo' ... you should just use your real object!

Comment: So inside of the value, I could add any data type? So could I add my  sorty object inside of the value parameter?

Comment: Hah! nvm your post clearly says I should be able to. Can you tell I have been wrestling this to long?

Comment: When I put my object inside of the string fieldOne, I get an error "Illegal type SortedDetailFields used in boxed expression."

Comment: @{@"field":sorty,@"value":"@(fieldone)} this did not work? (I'm not sure which object you want to put in there )